# Where can I find crafting recipe books?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

Most recipes you can just *do* by dragging stuff together in a mad science kind of way. But some only work after having read certain books. Right now, I've finally got 5 points in crafting and want to make some skill books, only I haven't found Secrets of the Scroll X.

Some walkthroughs mention individual crafting book locations, but I've not found a list of locations, and no definitive location for the book I need now. Are most of them just random? Are there certain vendors who carry books more frequently than others?

Answer (score 1):

Finally made it to the Teller of Secrets vendor at the End of Time. I bought all the Secrets of the Trade books for 36894 gold (bartering 2 from gear), read them all and got them added to the map, then sold them all back for 11077 gold. I haven't tracked them down in game yet, because you can't view the map for areas other than the one you're currently in. Several of the secrets had duplicate texts, as you can see below, despite having different volume numbers and different titles. I will report back later if they have different map locations. Most of these read like they're ability books (Aerothurge, Witchcraft etc.) and not actual crafting books, so we'll just have to see.

### Secrets of the Trade Volume I - Legend of the Lighthouse

> Some say a paranoid old Lighthouse keeper hid away his most effective defense mechanism in case of emergency.

### Secrets of the Trade Volume II - The Dark Kings Knowledge

> Many a great war leaves one with this particular spell at the Dark Kings side.

### Secrets of the Trade Volume III - The Cultist's Secret

> Some say entire towns of believers could be laid low by a single shot from this terrible skill.

### Secrets of the Trade Volume IV - The Knowledge of the Dead

> An aged necromancer left this ancient tome as his last legacy, hoping none would uncover the dark power he had set loose...

### Secrets of the Trade Volume V - Forgotten Legends

> An aged necromancer left this ancient tome as his last legacy, hoping none would uncover the dark power he had set loose...

### Secrets of the Trade Volume VI - Plundered Loot

> Some say that buried here is Pontius Pirate's preferred method of dealing with his enemies.

### Secrets of the Trade Volume VII - A Secret Grimoire

> Harness the power of forrest with this skill book, as rare as it is legendary.

### Secrets of the Trade Volume VIII - What the Witch Knew

> Harness the power of forrest with this skill book, as rare as it is legendary.

### Secrets of the Trade Volume IX - Forbidden Knowledge

> In the phantom forrests darkest dungeons, ancient secrets lie dormant.

### Secrets of the Trade Volume X - Snow and Ice

> In this land of winter, Ice magic was perfected many eons ago.

### Secrets of the Trade Volume XI - Sealed Secrets

> In the phantom forrests darkest dungeons, ancient secrets lie dormant.